# I am unable to change the color of a bootstrap button to close a modal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to change the color of my bootstrap close button, but it seems like I am unable to change the color of the "x"

Initially I thought no CSS was being applied to the `m-close` class, but after changing it from `color` to `background-color`, the background of the button was changed to white, while the "x" still remained black.

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="contactModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modalContact" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
       <div class="card bg-dark text-white" style="border-radius: 1.3rem;">
         <div class="modal-header">
           <button type="button" class="btn-close m-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">

           </button>
         </div>...
```

```css
.m-close {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rb2gk3u9/1/

Comment: Add `!important` after your css. This makes it have higher precedence over normal bootstrap elements

Comment: I tried `!important` but the button color still remains black

Answer (score 2):

Icon X in Bootstrap `.btn-close` is a `background-image` using SVG data URI, so you can change it using `color` in CSS.

If you want to change X icon to white, there is a Bootstrap class name for that. Just add class `btn-close-white` to that close button like this

```html
<button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-white" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by @Ashar is correct, you weren't able to change it becaus the icon inside of it isn't a phisical element, but an svg background-image, so there's no way (at least that i know) to "directly affecting" background images within css, except for one property, which are filters.

the .btn-close-white applies an "invert" filter which will make the trick, but is not going to be a pure brilliant white.

Better would be to put a real icon inside the button and hiding te background image.